# Is it possible to reach the property of a collection object that is not part of an interface

Tags: vba, excel

I have two classes of shapes and an interface. After I instantiate objects from each class and set their properties I add them to a collection. That's pretty straightforward. Then I declare a variable of type `MyInterface` and loop through the collection to add each shape. But there is an additional property for each type of shape that I want to set but which are not part of the interface. Is there a way to do this? I think other languages call this type casting but I am not sure. Does VBA support this? Any help is appreciated. My code is below:

**Interface** (*iShape*)

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Let Top(value As Long)
End Property
Public Property Get Top() As Long
End Property

Public Property Let Left(value As Long)
End Property
Public Property Get Left() As Long
End Property

Public Property Let Width(value As Long)
End Property
Public Property Get Width() As Long
End Property

Public Property Let Height(value As Long)
End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Long
End Property

Public Function Draw(obj As Worksheet) As Excel.Shape
End Function
```

**Class** (*cDiamond*)

```
Option Explicit

Private pTop As Long
Private pLeft As Long
Private pWidth As Long
Private pHeight As Long
Private pColor As Long

Implements iShape

'====================Properties====================
Public Property Let Top(value As Long)
    pTop = value
End Property
Public Property Get Top() As Long
    Top = pTop
End Property

Public Property Let Left(value As Long)
    pLeft = value
End Property
Public Property Get Left() As Long
    Left = pLeft
End Property

Public Property Let Width(value As Long)
    pWidth = value
End Property
Public Property Get Width() As Long
    Width = pWidth
End Property

Public Property Let Height(value As Long)
    pHeight = value
End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Long
    Height = pHeight
End Property

Public Property Let Color(value As Long)
    pColor = value
End Property
Public Property Get Color() As Long
    Color = pColor
End Property

'====================Methods====================
Public Function Draw(obj As Worksheet) As Excel.Shape
    Set Draw = obj.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeFlowchartOffpageConnector, Me.Left, Me.Top, Me.Width, Me.Height)
End Function

'====================Interface====================
Private Property Get iShape_Height() As Long
    iShape_Height = Height
End Property
Private Property Let iShape_Height(RHS As Long)
    Height = RHS
End Property

Private Property Get iShape_Left() As Long
    iShape_Left = Left
End Property
Private Property Let iShape_Left(RHS As Long)
    Left = RHS
End Property

Private Property Get iShape_Top() As Long
    iShape_Top = Top
End Property
Private Property Let iShape_Top(RHS As Long)
    Top = RHS
End Property

Private Property Get iShape_Width() As Long
    iShape_Width = Width
End Property
Private Property Let iShape_Width(RHS As Long)
    Width = RHS
End Property

Private Function iShape_Draw(obj As Worksheet) As Shape
    Set iShape_Draw = Draw(obj)
End Function
```

**Class** (*cTextbox*)

For the sake of brevity, this class is identical to *cDiamond* except it has a `Caption` property instead of a `Color` property.

**Module** (*mTest*)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    Dim d1 As cDiamond
    Set d1 = New cDiamond
    d1.Top = 10
    d1.Left = 10
    d1.Height = 25
    d1.Width = 25
    d1.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    c.Add d1

    Dim d2 As cDiamond
    Set d2 = New cDiamond
    d2.Top = 50
    d2.Left = 10
    d2.Height = 25
    d2.Width = 25
    d2.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    c.Add d2

    Dim t1 As cTextbox
    Set t1 = New cTextbox
    t1.Top = 90
    t1.Left = 10
    t1.Height = 25
    t1.Width = 25
    t1.Caption = "Textbox"
    c.Add t1

    Dim shp As iShape
    For Each shp In c
        shp.Draw wks
        ' I would like to set the color or caption properties depending on the type of shape in the collection.
    Next shp
    Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If the shape whose property you need to set is "not part of the interface" then where is it?  To which interface are you referring?   Which "additional property for each type of shape" are you referring to?

Comment: @ashleedawg I only have one interface for the common properties of each class. The additional properties are `Color` for `cDiamond` and `Caption` for `cTextbox`. I want to change the color for diamond objects and add a caption for textbox objects in the collection. But they are not part of the interface because diamond objects don't have a caption and textbox objects don't have a color. But I don't fully understand interfaces that well so I'm sure I am missing something.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, (and I don't fully understand interfaces either), you should be able to do what you want by declaring `shp` as of type variant.  `Dim shp : For Each shp in C ...`   Then you can retrieve or modify `shp.color` or `shp.caption`.  You may also want to change `Caption` to datatype `String` in  `cTextBox`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you very much!! I did catch the datatype for `Caption`. I also changed the variable of the `For...Each` loop to variant and tested for `TypeName` which worked. I also set a variable as type `Shape` since my class function returns a shape object. I will mark as correct if you want to post an answer. Otherwise, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, (and I don't fully understand interfaces either), you should be able to do what you want by declaring shp as of type variant.

```
Dim shp
For Each shp in C ...
```

`shp` will then take on the type of either `cDiamond` or `cTextbox` depending on which is retrieved from the `Collection`. Then you will be able to retrieve or modify `shp.color` or `shp.caption`. You may also want to change `Caption` to datatype `String` in `cTextBox`

Answer (score 1):

Declaring shp as object you will lose intellisense.  Another technique would be to have Interface return a reference to the instance of object.  Similarly to how `OLEObject.Object` returns the instance of the object that it is wrapping.  In my example I use `This` to return the instance of the class.

[image]

In this way you will have intellisense for all the common properties and methods.  We can also access the properties and methods that are unique to the classes that implement your interface using a `With` statement.

You'll need to first test check the type of the object.  Then use a `With` statement to temporarily instantiate a new Object of that type and write your code inside the `With` statement .

```
If TypeOf shp Is cTextbox Then
    With New cTextbox
        Msgbox .Caption
    End With
End If
```

Finally, you simply replace the `New` instance with the actual instance of the Object.

```
If TypeOf shp Is cTextbox Then
    With shp.This
        Msgbox .Caption
    End With
End If
```

### [image]

**Interface (iShape)**

```
Public Function This() As Object
End Function
```

---

**Classes cTextbox & cDiamond**

```
Public Function This() As Object
    Set This = Me
End Function

Public Function iShape_This() As Object
    Set iShape_This = This
End Function
```

---

**mTest.Test**

```
Dim shp As iShape
For Each shp In c
    shp.Draw wks

    If TypeOf shp Is cTextbox Then
        With shp.This
            MsgBox .Caption
        End With
    End If

    ' I would like to set the color or caption properties depending on the type of shape in the collection.
Next shp
```

Comment: It took me awhile to understand what you were doing. That's pretty cool! It seems similar, though not identical, to the `parent` property, no? Thanks!

Comment: Kinda sorta similar but not really.  A quick g-search gave me these two design patters which better describe it:  [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: I started use `this()` to return an self reference to an object for a project that I'm currently developing and I really like it.  My project uses a [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)  to create HTML.  I posted the base class here: [Creating HTML using a Builder Pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178814/creating-html-using-a-builder-pattern?s=1|62.6488).